# Alternate color every 4 items

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible with pure CSS to create a color grid that alternates every 4 items. Eg; First 4 items to have blue color, the next 4 to have red and then the next 4 back to blue and so on.

```html
<div>Item 1 = blue</div>
<div>Item 2 = blue</div>
<div>Item 3 = blue</div>
<div>Item 4 = blue</div>
<div>Item 5 = red</div>
<div>Item 6 = red</div>
<div>Item 7 = red</div>
<div>Item 8 = red</div>
<div>Item 9 = blue</div>
```

Any ideas? I know there is `nth-child(odd)` and `even` but not sure that helps here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a default rule for the red, and a rule that repeats with an offset for the blue it is possible.

The syntax of `8n+1` every 8 offset by 1, and then this is repeated to get 1 through 4.

```css
div {
  color: red;
}

div:nth-child(8n+1),
div:nth-child(8n+2),
div:nth-child(8n+3),
div:nth-child(8n+4) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>Item 1 = blue</div>
<div>Item 2 = blue</div>
<div>Item 3 = blue</div>
<div>Item 4 = blue</div>
<div>Item 5 = red</div>
<div>Item 6 = red</div>
<div>Item 7 = red</div>
<div>Item 8 = red</div>
<div>Item 9 = blue</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use some verbose *nth-child* logic - see demo below:

```css
div:nth-child(4n),
div:nth-child(4n - 1),
div:nth-child(4n - 2),
div:nth-child(4n - 3) {
  color: blue;
}

div:nth-child(8n),
div:nth-child(8n - 1),
div:nth-child(8n - 2),
div:nth-child(8n - 3) {
  color: red;
}

/* stylings */
body {
  counter-reset: counter;
}

div {
  counter-increment: counter;
}

div:after {
  content: counter(counter);
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what you're looking for.

Let me know if it doesn't

```css
div:nth-child(2n) {
  color:blue;
}
div:nth-child(3n) {
  color:green;
}
div:nth-child(4n) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Item 1 = blue</div>
  <div>Item 2 = blue</div>
  <div>Item 3 = blue</div>
  <div>Item 4 = blue</div>
  <div>Item 5 = red</div>
  <div>Item 6 = red</div>
  <div>Item 7 = red</div>
  <div>Item 8 = red</div>
  <div>Item 9 = blue</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your blue text is in green and red. :\ He wants blue to appear the first 4 times and then red for the next 4 and then back to blue for the next 4.